# How to sort classes/fields/methods/properties in a .NET assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, mono.cecil

I have an assembly of a program for which I don't have access to the source code and want to sort its classes alphabetically by their fully qualified name inside of the assembly, instead of using the order specified by the compiler used to generate it.

I've tried using Mono.Cecil for that, but it seems I can't change the order of classes within `ModuleDefinition.Types` property because it's a get-only `IEnumerable`.

So how do I change the order of the items of an assembly module? Or is it impossible to change it?

Comment: `So how do I change the order of the items of an assembly module?` do you want to change their order or do you want to display them in some order?

Comment: I want to change their order within the assembly, so that when I use tools like ILDasm they'll output them sorted.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I knew the answer, but I realized I don't know enough about Mono.Cecil. I *think* it's not possible to do this with Cecil, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: If you by any chance know of some other tool that can do it, go ahead and share with us. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it seems I can't change the order of classes within `ModuleDefinition.Types` property because it's a get-only `IEnumerable`.

Not quite, it's a get-only `Collection<T>`.

This means you can change the order of types in it by getting the list of types from the collection, sorting them, clearing `Types` and finally readding them back. In code:

```
var assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(inputPath);

var module = assembly.MainModule;

var sorted = module.Types.OrderBy(t => t.FullName).ToList();

module.Types.Clear();

foreach (var type in sorted)
{
    module.Types.Add(type);
}

assembly.Write(outputPath);
```

Comment: Thank you! The classes are now fully sorted! I was thinking of a similar way to this, but thought that would mess with class references, but it actually works.